# How to merge 2 linked lists into 1?

Tags: list, merge, linked-list

I have tried to find an answer but couldn't find a clear explenation.

i have the following code:

```
slist* mergeLists(slist *List1,slist *List2)

{
    slist *temp=*List1;

    while (temp->next!=NULL)
        temp=temp->next;

    temp->next=List2;

    return List1;
}
```

I Try to merge List1 with List2 and return List 1 (List 1->List 2).
but i have no idea how o continue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A search in my bookmarks yields this  [link](http://www.techfinite.net/2013/12/program-to-merge-two-linkedlist.html), which previously helped me achive the merging of two lists. What this basically does is

```
Node *nodeC;                           // The combined list
while(nodeA != null && nodeB != null) 
{
    if(nodeA->Id <= nodeB->Id)         // Sorting
    { 
        nodeC->Link = nodeA;           // Set nodeA to the link of the current node
        nodeC = nodeA;                 // Set nodeC to nodeA (which is now the current node)
        nodeA = nodeA->link; 
    }
    else 
    {
        nodeC->Link = nodeB;
        noceC = nodeB; 
        nodeB = nodeB->Link;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some real answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot some people don't know how to use links ;)

Comment: No offense, but saying "search this in some place" is not anasnswer

Comment: It was more like, click here and behold: the solution ;) Anyway, I added some simplified code, thanks for the comment.